# TextFormat and TextFields display different outside of FlashPlayer

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I have been using TextFields like this to render text for a game. I've been developing in FlashDevelop, so the SWF is compiled using the Flex compiler.

My problem is that this text is not displayed with the appropriate formatting when I view it inside the browser as opposed to a flashplayer (which looks fine). Different screen resolutions tend to vary in how they distort text in the browser. Why could this be?

```
  var welcomeText:TextField = new TextField();
//formatText creates a TextFormat object, sets those values into TextFormat
//then returns after doing TextField.defaultTextFormat = TextFormatObj;

            formatText(welcomeText, 3, 0xFFFFFF, "Courier");
            welcomeText.width = 385;
            welcomeText.height = 25;
            welcomeText.x = 60;
            welcomeText.y = 60;
            welcomeText.text = "Cogito ergo sum";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely happening because you are not embedding the font. Instead, you are using the Courier font available to they system (or browser). While this saves on file-size (the font is not packaged within the SWF), it doesn't always look so great.

In order to use an embedded font, you need to do 2 things

**1. Set "embedFonts" to true for your TextField**

```
welcomeText.embedFonts = true;
```

**2. Embed the font**

You can use meta data in your AS3 to embed the font file like this:

```
[Embed(source="C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\COURIER.TTF", fontFamily="Courier")]
var _courier:String;
myTextFormat.font = _courier;
```

Note: You can also create a font linkage in the library of Flash Professional. In the library, select "New Font...", name it. When done, right-click the font and select "Linkage..." give it a class name (say "Courier_Font")and export as a SWC. Add this to your class-path in your IDE and the font will be accessible like this:

```
var _font:Courier_Font = new Courier_Font();
myTextFormat.font = _font.fontName;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what the issue was. The difference wasn't in screen resolution or browsers, but in the OS. Renders fine on Windows, but in Mac and Linux the text suddenly had issues (reverting back to some default settings). Embedding in Flash Pro look straightforward, but as I'm using Flash Develop getting the text embedded is proving trickier than desired. That's another issue which seems to be extensively covered on this site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html).  I know I've had trouble in the past with formatting so I set a TextFormat object just as you do plus I use the

```
testfield.SetStyle()
```

command as well.  You can set a lot of parameters through SetStyle (font family, color, even text format) similar to this example...

```
TextFormat textStyle;
// Set properties for textstyle
textField.setStyle("textFormat", textStyle);
```

Hopefully this helps.  Just try to set it as many ways as possible I guess.